# Search for a value in multiple columns and return all results that are in the right column of the found column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Search the value "thisisit" in column A and then search in this line for all "de" columns and return me what is in the columns to the right of it. If multiple results are returned, return the results in one cell but separate these results with a line break.

```
A1          | B1        | C1          | D1          | E1        | F1        | G1
thisisit    | de        | Bicycle     | en          | Car       | de        | Boot

A3
Bicycle (line break)
Boot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, QUERY({TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 INDIRECT(MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)&":"&MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)), 
 MOD(COLUMN(1:1), 2)=0)), {QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 INDIRECT(MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)&":"&MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)), 
 MOD(COLUMN(1:1)-1, 2)=0)), "offset 1", 0); ""}},
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'de'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Ok I changed the commas into semilicons because I use Google Sheets but now I get the error:  "query takes only 3 arguments this is number 4" and "error in parsing the formula"

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I opened a example sheet which have now other names of the table but the same structure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fWQgo-55U0eEh6MSZ401Xhe9lG5K09V_WRRzLiWnTcg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w9eyrFtcPGWvrEXqvBjOTNIomfCiFOY9U1HUh_JFhmo/edit#gid=1772814825

Comment: Do you have a modification for the above formula which gives me all the results back for a whole column like an array instead only for one line?

Comment: `=QUERY({TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 INDIRECT(MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)&":"&MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)), 
 MOD(COLUMN(1:1), 2)=0)), {QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 INDIRECT(MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)&":"&MATCH("thisisit", A1:A)), 
 MOD(COLUMN(1:1)-1, 2)=0)), "offset 1", 0); ""}},
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'de'", 0)`